# ul widht auto stretch with maximum height

Tags: html, css

I have an html  structure roughly like this:

```
<ul class="groupmenu-drop">
  <li class="level1"> 
     <a href="#"> BMW </a>
     <ul class="level1 groupmenu-drop">
        <li class="level2"> i3 </li>
        <li class="level2"> i5 </li>
        <li class="level2"> i7 </li>   
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1"> 
     <a href="#"> Mercedez Benz </a>
     <ul class="level1 groupmenu-drop">
        <li class="level2"> a-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> e-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> c-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> s-class </li>     
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

my current css:

```
ul.groupmenu-drop{
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 99; 
    list-style: none none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

li{
    list-style: none
    padding: 8px 15px;
    min-width: 230px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.groupmenu-drop > li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

I want to make the first ul to have maximum height so when the level1 li and its child overlapping the ul height it will make the ul stretch its width and the level1 li will fill it, here's what i want it to look  like:

[image: sketch]

Comment: can you share entire code with CSS?

Comment: _“here's what i want it to look like”_ - what, you want to make the second “Mercedez Benz” list show up _twice_, regardless of that element being present in the DOM only once …?

Comment: @CBroe i dont say i want to rendered it twice, its just an example of what i want to look like

Comment: Still doesn’t make sense to me. (And since I see all the answers so far duplicate that element in the markup to achieve what you have shown in that picture, I think others might not really get it either.) If you want to show two different scenarios, then it might make sense to use two images, or at least clearly mark what should be which in the image. Or you could just say, I want those two lists next to each other if there’s enough space, and if not the second one should go below the first ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Using `flex-flow: column wrap;` will display `li` as columns, will and wrap if necessary or there is space available vertically.

```css
.groupmenu-drop:not(.level1) {
  max-height: 200px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul class="groupmenu-drop">
  <li class="level1">
    <a href="#"> BMW </a>
    <ul class="level1 groupmenu-drop">
      <li class="level2"> i3 </li>
      <li class="level2"> i5 </li>
      <li class="level2"> i7 </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1">
    <a href="#"> Mercedez Benz </a>
    <ul class="level1 groupmenu-drop">
      <li class="level2"> a-class </li>
      <li class="level2"> e-class </li>
      <li class="level2"> c-class </li>
      <li class="level2"> s-class </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1">
    <a href="#"> Audi </a>
    <ul class="level1 groupmenu-drop">
      <li class="level2"> a-class </li>
      <li class="level2"> e-class </li>
      <li class="level2"> c-class </li>
      <li class="level2"> s-class </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: if i use flex-flow: column wrap the ul width will not stretch but the rest of the li will align vertical perfectly

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```css
.groupmenu-drop {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.level1 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.groupmenu-drop .groupmenu-drop {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="groupmenu-drop">
  <li class="level1"> 
     <a href="#"> BMW </a>
     <ul class="level1 groupmenu-drop">
        <li class="level2"> i3 </li>
        <li class="level2"> i5 </li>
        <li class="level2"> i7 </li>   
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1"> 
     <a href="#"> Mercedez Benz </a>
     <ul class="level1 groupmenu-drop">
        <li class="level2"> a-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> e-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> c-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> s-class </li>     
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level1"> 
     <a href="#"> Mercedez Benz </a>
     <ul class="level1 groupmenu-drop">
        <li class="level2"> a-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> e-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> c-class </li>
        <li class="level2"> s-class </li>     
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```